# Get me to calculate displacement. I don't how what will be the formula according to this program

Tags: c++

```
class Vehicle;
class Point {
private:
    float x, y;
public:
    Point(float x = 0,float y = 0){
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
    void move_north(float num){
        y = y + num;
    }
    void move_south(float num){
        y = y - num;
    }
    void move_west(float num){
        x = x - num;
    }
    void move_east(float num){
        x = x + num;
    }
    float getX(){
        return x;
    }
    float getY(){
        return y;
    }
    void print() const {
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << x << " " << y << endl;
    }
    
    friend class Vehicle;
};

class Vehicle {
private:
    Point starting_position;
    Point current_position;
    float distance_covered = 0;
    float calculate_displacement() const {
       ** how to calculate it I dont understand **
    }
    public:
    Vehicle(Point p) {
        starting_position.x = p.x;
        starting_position.y = p.y;
        current_position.x = p.x;
        current_position.y = p.y;
    }
    void move_north(float num){
        distance_covered = distance_covered + num;
        current_position.y = current_position.y + num;
    }
    void move_south(float num){
        distance_covered = distance_covered + num;
        current_position.y = current_position.y - num;
    }
    void move_west(float num){
        distance_covered = distance_covered + num;
        current_position.x = current_position.x - num;
    }
    void move_east(float num){
        distance_covered = distance_covered + num;
        current_position.x = current_position.x + num;
    }
    void print() const {
        cout << "Starting position: ";
        starting_position.print();
        cout << "current_position: ";
        current_position.print();
        cout << "Distance covered: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << distance_covered << endl;
        **Here calling calculate_displacement()**
        cout << "Displacement: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << calculate_displacement() << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    float initial_x, initial_y;
    cin >> initial_x >> initial_y;
    Point starting_position(initial_x, initial_y);
    Vehicle vehicle(starting_position);
    int number_of_moves;
    char direction;
    float units;
    cin >> number_of_moves;
    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_moves; i++) {
        getchar();
        cin >> direction >> units;
        switch(direction) {
            case 'N':
                vehicle.move_north(units);
                break;
            case 'S':
                vehicle.move_south(units);
                break;
            case 'W':
                vehicle.move_west(units);
                break;
            case 'E':
                vehicle.move_east(units);
                break;
        }
    }
    vehicle.print();
}
```

```
Explaination : I want to know the displacment formula to calculate it between two points on graph
               the input is :
               1.1 3.3
               5
               N 2.1 W 2.5 S 2.1 E 3.1 N 0.6
               output expected 
               Starting position: 1.10 3.30
               current_position: 1.70 3.90
               Distance covered: 10.40
               Displacement: 0.85
So i want some one to help me guide further
```

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171864/how-to-calculate-the-displacement-between-points

Comment: Are you looking for Pythagoras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance between two points no matter the dimension is called [Euclidean_distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)

[image]

so your method is

```
float calculate_displacement() const
{
    return sqrt (delta_x*delta_x + delta_y*delta_y);
}
```

and

```
delta_x = starting_position.x - current_position.x
delta_y = starting_position.y - current_position.y
```